# LuaJIT FFI cdef doesn't understand 'class'?

Tags: c++, c, lua, ffi, luajit

```
class Myuser * MyClient_GetMyUser(AUser aUser);
```

This is the error for trying to declare that function with ffi.cdef:

```
Error: dllImport.lua:861: declaration specifier expected near 'class' at line 20
```

How is this possible? How would I go about declaring 'class' if I must do so within cdef?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`class` is a C++ keyword. It doesn't exist in C. LuaJIT expects C code, not C++ code in the FFI block.

As for how to work around this, it depends on what you're doing. Either you make that a C `struct`, or you find a different way to access it.